# Insert an element at index for linked list c++

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to insert a new element in a linked list at an indexed position. To do this I'm thinking to create a new node with the new data and make the previous node at index (n-1) point to the new node. Then, I want to delete the node that the (n-1) previously pointed to(whew).

```
bool LinkedList::InsertAtIndex(int value, int index) 
{
    LinkedListNode* temp = new LinkedListNode();

    temp->data = value;
    temp->next_node = NULL;

    if (index == 1) 
    {
        temp->next_node = head;
        head = temp;

        return true;
    } 

    LinkedListNode* temp2 = head;

    for (int i = 0; i<index-2; i++) 
    {
        temp2 = temp2->next_node;
    }

    temp->next_node = temp2->next_node;

    temp2->next_node = temp;

    delete [] temp;

    return true;
}
```

Had a little trouble with the formatting but it compiles. However at runtime a get a segmentation fault. I'm assuming my logic is wrong so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to make it on paper first, before you attempt to code it. For example, draw three boxes with arrows from one to the other, representing a linked list with three nodes. Then think about how you would put a new node between the first and second node, what arrows (links) you need to add, what arrows you need to modify. Implement that as code. Then go *back* to the paper, and start thinking about the corner cases, adding as a new first or last node, or when the list is empty.

Comment: And use debugger. You will probably see very fast, what is causing segfault

Comment: You should remove something like your debugging comments, this will help others here to be able to better understand your code.

Comment: Why do you want to *delete temp* after inserting it in the list?? There is no reason to do so, it just corrupts all your pointers in the LinkedList. Did I miss something?

Comment: sorry, i just realized your last sentence in the question (*Then, I want to delete the node that the (n-1) previously pointed to*). Deleted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is

```
delete [] temp;
```

`temp` is not an array, so you should free the memory via

```
delete temp;
```

Furthermore, I would recommend to use smart pointers instead of raw pointers (look for `std::shared_ptr` or Wikipedia to get started: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer)